# Ubuntu 18.04 Bluetooth Settings Missing from Upper Right Corner Menu

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome

TL;DR - The bluetooth settings usually available in the upper-right corner menu (along with sound, battery, user profile, power off) is only present when bluetooth is turned on, but disappears when bluetooth is turned off.

I'm a pretty long-term Ubuntu user, and have been using Ubuntu 18.04 for about a year on two different laptops. I just got a new M.2 NVMe SSD for one of the laptops and performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on there (I removed my SATA HDD for the time being and only have Ubuntu installed on this SSD - no dual booting).

I recently went to turn on the bluetooth to pair with my headphones, and looked for the bluetooth menu option from the upper right-corner menu. To my surprise it wasn't there (see image below).

[image: Bluetooth settings missing from upper-right corner while bluetooth is off.]

Instead, I had to open my settings, navigate to bluetooth, and then turn it on. Once I had done that, the ability to turn off bluetooth or go to bluetooth settings was added back to the upper-right corner menu (see image below).

[image: Bluetooth settings back where they normally are when bluetooth is on.]

But once I turn off bluetooth, that option goes away again. Anyone encounter this and know how to keep the bluetooth settings in that upper-right corner menu? I'm not looking for blueman or an indicator along the top bar - I'm looking to just permanently keep the bluetooth settings accessible in the corner menu regardless of whether bluetooth is on or off.

For reference, here is a screenshot of the menu on my previous installation on my old HDD, showing that the bluetooth menu should still be there when bluetooth is off.

[image: Bluetooth menu on previous installation.]

Comment: I note the OP's comment below that the issue resolved without any clear reason why, so closing as 'Can't be reproduced...'.

Answer (score 1):

run the below command and refresh the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r to bring the Bluetooth menu in the top right menu.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell had-bluetooth-devices-setup true
```

[image]

But once the bluetooth is off, the above gsettings key becomes false..
to lock the value to true, run the below script with root privileges.

```
#!/bin/bash

keys=/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-bt
locks=/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/bt

touch /etc/dconf/profile/user
echo "user-db:user" >> /etc/dconf/profile/user
echo "system-db:local" >> /etc/dconf/profile/user
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d
touch $keys
echo "[org/gnome/shell]" >> $keys
echo "had-bluetooth-devices-setup=true" >> $keys
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks
touch $locks
echo "/org/gnome/shell/had-bluetooth-devices-setup" >> $locks
dconf update
```

Logout and Logback in.

Please note that.. when you turnoff bluetooth.. you need to refresh gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r Enter to bring the bluetooth option to show in the list.

** to delete the changes in future, run the below commands with root privileges.

```
rm -r /etc/dconf/profile/user /etc/dconf/db/local.d
dconf update
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much!!!!! There's still an issue though - it works to show the menu once, but as soon as I toggle the bluetooth on and then off, it removes it from the menu again

Comment: @tbell answer edited.. Please review..

Comment: We're getting closer now - it still shouldn't require doing Alt+F2 r Enter every time I turn off the bluetooth though. Something in the code that turns off the bluetooth is not aware that we want this menu to persist

Comment: Well, 3 days later now, and the problem seems to have resolved itself... Can't explain it! Maybe there was a kernel update or something that I didn't notice. Thanks for your help YuganTej!