# Bluetooth Indicator Disappears after Turning off

Tags: gnome, 20.04, bluetooth, indicator

I've checked the threads [Bluetooth indicator disappears (...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293360/bluetooth-indicator-disappears-on-turning-off-bluetooth) and [Bluetooth Settings Missing from Upper Right Corner (...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203854/ubuntu-18-04-bluetooth-settings-missing-from-upper-right-corner-menu)
, but thus far the solutions didn't quite solve my problem.

The issue I'm having is, that most times when I turn off the Bluetooth from the top panel (in reality I'm using the `dash-to-panel` gnome extension but even after disabling all the extensions and using the default top panel, the issue still persists), the Bluetooth indicator disappears, and if I want to turn it on again, I have to go to the settings and turn it on there, which can get annoying from time to time.

Not sure if it's a bug or a feature. The first link mentioned above I tried the accepted solution, it showed that I needed some dependencies, and when I went on to install said dependencies, it gave me the error that they couldn't be installed, vaguely speaking (I'm a bit of a new Linux user still so it took me a while to install some of the packages in order to pursue that solution, and when I managed to install them and got shown the error when installing the dependencies I just sort of figured that there must be an easier way to resolve this issue).

The second link, a user provides a script solution that runs in the background, but in order for it to have an effect, the display must be reloaded (by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing r and pressing return) every time the Bluetooth is turned off via the top panel, which I wouldn't find very ideal.

I know that the setting `had-bluetooth-devices-setup`, in the `dconf` editor, when set to `True` shows the Bluetooth indicator even when it's turned off, which is what I would like. But, almost every time I turn the Bluetooth off, that setting gets turned off automatically, making the Bluetooth indicator disappear.

I'm experiencing this issue on a laptop with Ubuntu installed on it. However, I also have a personal computer with Pop_OS! installed. In the computer with Pop_OS! installed, when the bluetooth is turned off, the indicator doesn't disappear from the top panel menu, without fail; it remains in the menu in the top panel when clicking there, and I don't have to go to the settings to turn the bluetooth on. The opposite happens in the Ubuntu laptop; upon turning the bluetooth off from the top panel menu, the bluetooth indicator just disappears, and I'm forced to go into settings if I wish to turn the bluetooth back on. If there was a way to port the bluetooth behaviour from Pop_OS! to Ubuntu then that would be great.

For reference, here is how it looks like on the Ubuntu laptop when bluetooth is turned on:

[image: Bluetooth indicator is present when bluetooth is turned on]

And here's how the menu looks on the Ubuntu laptop upon clicking and the bluetooth is turned off:

[image: Bluetooth indicator disappears from menu when turned off]

This is how it looks like when the bluetooth is turned off on the desktop computer with Pop_OS! installed:

[image: Bluetooth indicator does not disappear when turned off on Pop_os!]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not at all understand the question. Are you using Pop_OS!? Or are you comparing two computers running two OSes, and you want the target computer to act the same way as it does in Pop_OS? I run stock Ubuntu and do not see the same issue you might be reporting ...

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have a laptop which has Ubuntu installed with the target issue. I also have a PC that has Pop_OS! installed which is the computer I'm comparing the laptop to. The bluetooth indicator disappears from the top panel when I turn it off on the Ubuntu laptop; on the PC with Pop_OS! however, the bluetooth indicator does not disappear upon turning off. What I am attempting is, to prevent the bluetooth indicator from vanishing from the top panel menu upon turning off on the Ubuntu laptop

Answer (score 7):

Type in the below command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell had-bluetooth-devices-setup true
```

Press Alt+F2 and type

```
r
```

Thats it!!!

Comment: explanation would be helpful, but it solved the problem. thx

Comment: Thanks for nice fix. But please also explain. :)

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me permanently. after restart (or multiple restarts) it is back to where it was before...

Comment: The `gsettings` thingy worked but the `r` didn't. I guess the purpose was to re-login which indeed did the job.